# Why does "overflow: hidden" make the navbar full width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navbar. But I found something confusing during the implementation.

The question is about the `.navbar` class in the css file. Why does `overflow: hidden` make the navbar full width?

Here is my code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial; 
}
.navbar {
    background-color: #f3f2f6;
    border: 1px solid #e9e8e9;
    overflow: hidden;  /* why overflow: hidden ????? */
}
.navbar button {
    background-color: inherit; 
    padding: 14px 16px;
    float: left;
    border: none; 
    outline: none; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar button:hover {
    background-color: #c6c5c6;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>
        Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:
    </p>

    <div class="navbar">
        <button >London</button>
        <button >Paris</button>
        <button >Tokyo</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Screenshot Without Overflow:**

[image: Screenshot Without Overflow]

**Screenshot With Overflow:**

[image: Screenshot With Overflow]

Comment: Because your buttons are floated, they don't give the div any width.

Comment: Yes, floats are put over the parent element and they don't give any size. A fix to this is to set the overflow property. Setting it to auto will also do the same, but will send items below and make the div height grow if you exceed the width. Another solution, which I do the most is to add a div with style: clear:both; at the end of the floated items.

Comment: @sideroxylon _“Because your buttons are floated, they don't give the div any width.”_ - they don’t need to give it any, it _has_ a width (and as a block element, that’s “full” width already.) What it doesn’t have because the children are floated, is a height.

Comment: @FucziFuczi So, your solution is to give the floated elements a size right? Also, setting the overflow property is the same.

Comment: @Connor its a common issue when using floats, I'd suggest this article from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) even though its a bit old, but its very good to understand whats happening. If you prefer a more updated approach checkout the [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)